# Find the mean and variance of the total number of spots obtained when 60 dice are thrown?

Tags: probability, random-variables

I'm not sure what they mean by spots, do they mean the number that pops up, like if I throw 1 dice, 3 pops up, so that's 3 spots?

How do I go about solving this? This is part of Expected Value and Variance.

What I do know is we are throwing a dice 60 times, right? So we have 60 bernoulli trials? Do I find the probability of each "Spot" that appears? So the probability it rolls 1 would be $$\frac{1}{6}$$

Comment: Yeah, "spots" just means the result of the die.  (This is confusing since some dice use actual numerals -- maybe not common for $6$-sided dice but very common for $8$-sided, $20$-sided dice etc.)  So the question is simply asking about $X=$ the total of the $60$ dice.

Comment: Ok but the probability of each outcome is 1/6... Im not sure what to do next.

Comment: Imagine you are throwing just $1$ die, not $60$.  Do you know how to calculate the expected value (i.e. average)?  The variance?

Comment: E(X) = the sum of all u in omega of  P(X) * X(u), so P(X) = 1/6, and X(u), Im not sure what X(U) would be.

Comment: Is it 1/6 + 2/6 + 3/6 + 4/6 + 5/6 + 6/6?

Comment: I found the variance and expected value, but I dont know what to do next.

Comment: For the variance you need the first formula here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_uncorrelated_variables_(Bienaym%C3%A9_formula) -- and note that it only applies because each die is independent.

Comment: Asked again at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3163668/18398

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Yes, your interpretation is correct.

1. Let $X$ be the number of spots obtained when one die is thrown. Can you find $m = \mathbb{E}[X]$ and $s = \mathrm{Var} X$? (**Note:** this is not a Bernoulli trial.)
2. Express number of spots for $60$ dice in terms of $m$ and $s$, and plug in values from (1) to get your answers.

**UPDATE**

Once you know $m$ and $s$ from part (1), let's setup up the case of the 60 dice. You throw 60 dice, and get the outcomes $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{60}$. The expected total number of dots is
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[ \sum_{k=1}^{60} X_k\right]
 = \sum_{k=1}^{60} \mathbb{E}\left[ X_k\right]
 = 60m.
$$
Can you do the same to variance?

Comment: I'm not sure. When there's 1 spot, the probability is $(\frac{1}{6})^{60}$?

Comment: @Stuy you are tossing **one** die and counting the number of spots. What outcomes are there? What is the probability of each outcome? What is the expected value? What is the variance?

Comment: You toss one die, and the outcomes are {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}. The probability of each outcome is 1/6. But in this case we toss 60 dies....

Comment: @Stuy see the update

Comment: the variance is 105/36 and the expected value is 21/6