# Mean and variance of multiple dice throw

Tags: probability

I'm really not understanding the problem at all and what it's asking:

[image]

Comment: What about it do you not understand? The mean number of spots? The variance?

Comment: The variance, the mean, like I really do not understand what to do with it.

Comment: Try computing the mean of all possible dice rolls? The sum of all dots for each possible set of rolls, divided by the total number of rolls (Hint: since each roll is independent, what can you do here). For variance, note that that variance of a sum of independent random variables is the sum of variances of those variables.

Comment: First just compute the mean (or average).  Take the average on each die and multiply it by 60.  Easy!

Comment: Wait. Is it one dice over 60 throws or 60 dice(s?) thrown together and the sum of spots? Isn't there a difference?

Comment: Haven't you asked this [exact (homework?) question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3163225/find-the-mean-and-variance-of-the-total-number-of-spots-obtained-when-60-dice-ar) already?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the mean and variance of the total number of spots obtained when 60 dice are thrown?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3163225/find-the-mean-and-variance-of-the-total-number-of-spots-obtained-when-60-dice-ar)

Comment: Why include an image when you could just type the question?

Answer (score 1):

The mean of a uniform distribution (for each die) is of course

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^6 i}{6} = 7/2$$

The variance for a single die is

$$\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^6 (i - 7/2)^2}{6} = \frac{35}{12}$$

So by the linearity principle for 60 rolls we have the mean is $60 \cdot 7/2 = 210$, and the variance is $60 \cdot \frac{35}{12} = 175$.

(Incidentally, the technical name for the "spots" is "pips.")

Answer (score 1):

Let the random sequence $(X_k)_{k=1}^{~~~60}$ be the results of sixty rolls of a fair, six-sided, die.  All $X_k$ are independent and identically *uniformly distributed* over the discrete support $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

$$\mathsf E(X_k)=\tfrac 72\\\mathsf {Var}(X_k)=\tfrac {91}6$$

Let $X$ be the random variable representing the sum of these results. Thus $X:=\sum_{k=1}^{60}X_k$.

We seek $\mathsf E(X)$ and $\mathsf{Var}(X)$, the expectation and variance for this sum.

You must now apply the rules you've been taught for these things.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(X)&=\mathsf E(\sum_{k=1}^{60} X_k)\\[1ex]&=&&\text{Linearity of Expectation}\\[1ex]&=\\[3ex]\mathsf{Var}(X)&=\mathsf{Var}(\sum_{k=1}^{60} X_k)\\[1ex]&=&&\text{Bilinearity of Covariance}\\[1ex]&=\end{align}$$